# Where does Turbo Geth store its data files?

Tags: chaindata

I recently started using TurboGeth and I have a question. Where does Turbo Geth store its data files?

Answer (score 3):

On the Mac, I found the data folder in `~/Library/TurboGeth`. You can change the location with the `--datadir` setting.

On Linux, the location is `~/.local/share/turbogeth`